# Type casting issues

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I hava a code snippet as below:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    virtual ~ ClassA() {};
    virtual void FunctionA() {cout << "ClassA" << endl;}
};
class ClassB
{
public:
    virtual void FunctionB() {};
};
class ClassC : public ClassA, public ClassB
{
public:
    void FunctionA(){cout << "why" << endl;}
    void FunctionB(){cout << "class C funb" << endl;}
};

ClassC aObject;
ClassA* pA = &aObject;
ClassB* pB = &aObject;
ClassC* pC = &aObject;

int main()
{
    void* pvoid = static_cast<void *> (pB);
    ClassA* pA2 = static_cast<ClassA*>(static_cast<ClassC*>(pB));

    return 0;
}
```

Is the type-cast to `pvoid` and `pA2` right? Or both of them are wrong?
(I tried to compile it, have not got errors)

Comment: Both of them are correct..are you getting any specific warning/errors?

Comment: No warnings or errors.

Comment: @JackSparrow: Often, invalid casts won't give compile-time errors or warnings, since the purpose of a cast is to subvert the type system that would catch those errors; it's a good idea to carefully check that any cast you do use is valid.

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for confirmation. My main intention was to know whether he is getting warning/errors somewhere else and he is relating it to this cast.

Comment: @Mike: but I got your point :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour It a choice question in a written examination, is this a bad question?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin: It's a reasonable test for understanding of the C++ object model. In a job interview, it would make me nervous that such knowledge might be needed on the job; dodgy casts like these shouldn't be needed in properly designed code, and code that needs them is likely to be riddled with bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pvoid` is "right" in the sense that it gives you the address of the `ClassB` subobject of `aObject` as an untyped pointer. The only useful thing you can do with it is cast it back to `ClassB*`. Note that the cast here is redundant, since any pointer can be implicitly converted to `void*`.

`pA2` is correctly initialised to point to the `ClassA` subobject of `aObject`. Since this is a "cross-cast" (i.e. neither type is derived from the other, but they are both base classes of some derived class), you either need to convert via the derived type as you've done, or use `dynamic_cast` if the derived type is not known at compile time.

Comment: You mean common most-derived class, right?

Comment: @Angew: Indeed, already corrected.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "right," but both definitions are legal and have well-defined semantics. `pvoid` will point to the `ClassB` subobject of `aObject`, while `pA2` will point to its `ClassA` subobject.